# Bash: verify that process has stopped

Tags: bash, unix

I'm working on script meant to start/stop a set of services. For stopping, it has to terminate many processes which take a while and might hang.

The script needs to verify that the process has indeed terminated, and send an email if such does not happen after a given period.

This is what I have:

```
pkill -f "stuff"

for i in {1..30}; do
    VERIFICATIONS=$i
    if verification_command then
        echo "It's gone"
        break
    fi
    sleep 2
done

if [ $VERIFICATIONS -ge 30 ]; then
   echo "failed to terminate"
   # send mail
fi
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: did you take a look at [return codes](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what I believe to be the best approach, based on [napcae's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/667418/bash-verify-that-process-has-stopped?noredirect=1#comment843489_667418): use a function.

```
assert_service_stopped () {
    for i in {1..30}; do
        if verification_command then
            echo "It's gone"
            return 0
        fi
        sleep 2
    done
    echo "It hangs dude!"
    return 1
}        

pkill -f "stuff"

if ! assert_service_stopped; then
    echo "failed to terminate"
    # send mail
fi
```

This has the advantage of allowing many assertions easily, and when there is no action required (like sending the email) the assertions can be performed last and the script exit status will reflect the assertions result.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which part you wish to improve. As for the killing, many processes store their own pid (=Process id) in the directory /var/run, in a file of extension .pid which contains only their pid, nothing else.

This pid is used by the programs to kill themselves (commit suicide?). If the program restarts itself (a frequent cause of one's inability to kill a program), the new pid will differ from the old one. All of this applies specifically to services, i.e., program you can stop with

```
 sudo service sshd stop
```

(in Debian and derivatives). You may perhaps consider implementing a similar mechanism.